# Margins that differ for the Headers and Footers from the body of the document

Tags: google-docs

Is there away, inside of Google Documents, of creating a header/footer that has no margins, but to give the body a set of margins? I've set the margins to be 0 for placing a drawing in the header, but I would prefer that the body text not to start at the 0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Having different margins for both the header and the body is as simple as clicking `Insert` > `Header` or `Footer`, and adjusting the margin arrow to the specifications that you desire. An example screenshot of a Google doc with different margins for the header and body:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! Thanks. I was thinking it could only be set via Page Setup. Thanks for the screen grab!